# Trying to make this VBA code run faster / possibly make it easier to read and update?

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies for the long code below in advance. The code simply looks at 1 cell in sheet 2 that is a date to determine what to do with the cells in sheet 1. The code that I have below works, but it takes about 20 seconds to run it which seems like more than it should, and I feel like the code could be a lot shorter (if only I was better with coding *frowns*  ) I had to find a similar code online that would work, I figure it's not the best one to use in this situation.

End goal here is to take cell C:24 from sheet2 and find this date in Row 4 of sheet1. Then in sheet 1 I am just copying and pasting cells as values in their specific rows in that same column. The rows are listed below (I only need the cells in those rows for the specific column pasted as a value)

Example:
Sheet2 cell C:24 = 9/2/2021
In sheet1 "9/2/2021" is in column ABC:4
According to the code below I would want ABC:18 , ABC:19 (and so on) copied and pasted as a value in the same cell that they are currently in (they are currently formulas in their respective cells)

```
Public Sub Paste_Amounts_As_Values()
Dim todayDate, tomorrowDate As Date
Dim sourceID, targetID As Integer
Dim countdate As Range
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim aRowVal, bRowVal, cRowVal, dRowVal, eRowVal, fRowVal, gRowVal, hRowVal, jRowVal, kRowVal, 
lRowVal, mRowVal, nRowVal, oRowVal, pRowVal, qRowVal, rRowVal, sRowVal As String

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

todayDate = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C24").Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastcol = wS.Cells(4, 4).End(xlToRight).Column
'dateRow = wS.Range("C24").Cells(4, lastcol).Value

ReDim selectData(1 To lastcol) As Variant

For i = 1 To lastcol - 1
selectData(i) = wS.Cells(4, i + 1)
Next i

For i = 1 To lastcol - 1
If selectData(i) = todayDate Then  'Cells to Copy
    
    aRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(18).Formula
    bRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(19).Formula
    
    cRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(29).Formula
    dRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(30).Formula
    
    eRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(40).Formula
    fRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(41).Formula
    
    gRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(51).Formula
    hRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(52).Formula
    
    jRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(62).Formula
    kRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(63).Formula
    
    lRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(73).Formula
    
    mRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(84).Formula
    
    nRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(94).Formula
    
    oRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(105).Formula
    
    pRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(115).Formula
    qRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(116).Formula
    
    rRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(126).Formula
    
    sRowVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(179).Formula
    
    sourceID = i + 1
    'Debug.Print aRowVal
    'Debug.Print bRowVal
    
   End If
Next i


If sourceID = 0 Then
MsgBox ("There is no match date with Today")
Else
For i = 1 To lastcol - 1
    If selectData(i) = todayDate Then  'Pasting as Value
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(18) = aRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(18, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(19) = bRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(19, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(19, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(29) = cRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(29, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(29, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(30) = dRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(30, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(30, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(40) = eRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(40, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(40, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(41) = fRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(41, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(41, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(51) = gRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(51, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(51, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(52) = hRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(52, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(52, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(62) = jRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(62, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(62, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(63) = kRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(63, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(73) = lRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(73, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(73, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(84) = mRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(84, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(84, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(94) = nRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(94, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(94, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(105) = oRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(105, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(105, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(115) = pRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(115, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(115, sourceID)
         ActiveSheet.Cells(116) = qRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(116, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(116, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(126) = rRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(126, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(126, sourceID)
         
         ActiveSheet.Cells(179) = sRowVal
         ActiveSheet.Cells(179, sourceID) = ActiveSheet.Cells(179, sourceID)
         
         
         
         targetID = i + 1
        'Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(9, i + 1)
        'Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(11, i)
    End If
Next i
If targetID = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("There is no match date with Tomorrow")
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have working code that you are asking for peer review to improve, you should ask your question on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Didnt know that was a thing, new to the site. Thanks!

Comment: I was told that Code Review was not meant for this.

Comment: Are your dates actual dates or strings that look like dates?

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry - extremely new to code. The dates in sheet2 are actual dates "9/2/2021" while the dates in sheet1 are showing as dates but they are formulas "=workday(ABC4,1,0) so I think that would be a string that looks like a date?

Comment: I'm not following your copy/paste section - `Cells(18)` is R1, but `Cells(18, sourceID)` would be J18 (assuming a match in column 10/J  When using `Cells` is always best to provide both row and column values...

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry there's confusion on my end as well. Not sure what you mean by R1, J18 or 10J.
This might help ? - To make it sound more simple, in a way I just want to do a find from the date in sheet2 to sheet1, then once i find what column that date is location in sheet1, I want to copy the numbers in the rows of the code and paste them as values over themselves but only in the same column that they're currently in. I don't want to move anything

Comment: "R1" etc are ranges addresses on sheet1

Comment: As you mentioned you are new to code, this doesn't do what you think it does: `Dim todayDate, tomorrowDate As Date` You need to specify every type so more like `Dim todayDate As Date, tomorrowDate As Date` otherwise your first one will be a variant instead of a date. You can also put multiple types on one line like so: `Dim todayDate As Date, tomorrowDate As Date, sourceID As Long, targetID As Long, countdate As Range, wS As Worksheet` and lastly don't use Integer in VBA, always use Long instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is following your posted code but refactored to use an array of column numbers:

```vb
Public Sub Paste_Amounts_As_Values()
    
    Dim todayDate As Long
    Dim sourceID As Long, targetID As Long
    Dim countdate As Range, m, rngMatch As Range
    Dim wS As Worksheet, arrCols, col

    todayDate = CLng(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C24").Value) '>>Long for matching
    
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'range with dates
    Set rngMatch = wS.Range("D4", wS.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    'any match ?
    m = Application.Match(todayDate, rngMatch, 0)
    
    If IsError(m) Then 'no match found?
        MsgBox "No match on " & wS.Name & " for " & todayDate
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    arrCols = Array(18, 19, 29, 30, 40, 41, 51, 52, 62, 63, 73, _
                    74, 84, 94, 105, 115, 116, 126, 179)
    sourceID = rngMatch.Cells(m).Column 'matched column
    
    For Each col In arrCols
        wS.Cells(1, col).Value = wS.Cells(1, col).Formula
        wS.Cells(col, sourceID).Value = wS.Cells(col, sourceID).Value
    Next col
    
    'skipped end part with "tomorrow" - not clear what that is...
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great! The tomorrow part in the second half wasn't needed, just a part of a code I found. Was just looking for a way to limit the amount of strings I had and things to update when I need to update the code. thank you!! :)